# Sending SMS with variable message

Tags: sms

I want a mobile web to send a specific message with following link "sms:number?body=text".

The best case scenario would be client inputting his ID once (either through registering or just by inputting the ID into form) and then he would be able to tap on the link with the additional output ("sms:number?body=text+ID".)

The reason for this is that the client should be able to ask about his account balance through predefined text message with as little effort as possible as the ID number is quite long and inputting the number every time would be quite tiring but I would be happy even with a simple form where you can input the ID.

The problem is, I have no idea where to start, what would be the best approach and so on. Any suggestions?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, fixed.